# Share operator with nested observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I create a game module that is responsible for loading the player's `buildings`, and then modifying the fetched objects to an extended building class containing an additional field - **remainingTime**, informing how many seconds are left to complete the upgrading lvl of buildings (this field is refreshed every second).

`buildings` -> `buildingsWithDiff` -> `buildingsWithTimer`

1. Loading `buildings`
2. Map `buildings` to `buildingsWithDiff` to know the **difference** between the date on which the **timer starts date** and the **end upgrading date**
3. Map `buildingsWithDiff` to `buildingsWithTimer` which subtracts the **number of ticks** from the resulting **difference**

```ts
class Building {
  name: string;
  lvl: number;
  endDate: Date; // date of upgrading of the building
}

class BuildingWithDiff extends Building {
  diffTime: number; // difference of seconds between the currentDate and the endDate;
}

class BuildingWithTimer extends BuildingWithDiff {
  remainingTime: number; // seconds left to complete upgrading a building
}

/* ------------- */

const getBuildings$ = (store: Store): Observable<Building[]> => {
  const buildings$: Observable<Building[]> = store.select(
    (appState: AppState) => appState.buildings
  ); // source
  return buildings$;
};

const getBuildingsWithTimers$ = (
  store: Store
): Observable<BuildingWithTimer[]> => {
  const buildings$: Observable<Building[]> = getBuildings$(store);

  const buildingsWithDiff$: Observable<BuildingWithDiff[]> = buildings$.pipe(
    map((buildings) =>
      buildings.map((building) => {
        const currentDate: Date = new Date();
        const diffTime: number =
          Math.ceil(
            building.endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()
          ) / 1000;

        return {
          ...building,
          diffTime,
        };
      })
    )
  );

  const buildingsWithTimer$: Observable<BuildingWithTimer[]> = buildingsWithDiff$.pipe(
    switchMap((buildingsWithDiff) =>
      timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        map((tick: number) =>
          buildingsWithDiff.map((buildingWithDiff) => {
            const remainingTime: number = buildingWithDiff.diffTime - tick;

            return {
              ...buildingWithDiff,
              remainingTime,
            };
          })
        )
      ),
      // share()? - it doesn't work :(
    )
  );

  return buildingsWithTimer$;
};
```

### Multicasting nested timers - How to?

Subscribing to the selector above generates errors because there are several observers and not all of them run at the same time. Adding the `share` operator **doesn't work**. Where could the problem be?

There are two places where this is subscribed:

- `trigger`- a function that is called in ngxsOnInit (waits for `remainingTime <= 0` to dispatch the appropriate action)
- `building component` - angular component which displays the remaining time

The application works fine when I turn it on on the subpage where this component exists - *both observers display the same tick value in the timer*.

The problem is when I exit the subpage where the component was, because the `trigger` works **all the time** and the ticks are still counted but the component ends the subscription and when I want to return to the subpage, the ticks are counted from zero.

**Ultimately, there are two different ticks.**

Comment: What's the actual error you get?

Comment: When are you using these? Could be the store is not bootstrapped yet.

Comment: Ha. I'm not used to seeing functions named with a trailing `$`. Threw me for a loop. Does the stream returned by `getBuildings$()` emit more than once? I'm assuming not, it's just a query to your data?

Comment: @MrkSef - in this simple example it's a normal query, but it's not always the case in my application. In other, more advanced modules, the data changes during the application is running

Comment: @Richard.Davenport - I edited main post

Comment: If you change `return buildingsWithTimer$;` to `return buildingsWithTimer$.pipe(share());` - what happens? Nothing different? I would expect it to work, though you may lose the first value. You can use publish and connect to control that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to use the `share()` - it doesn't do anything... maybe it's because there is a nested `timer` in `switchMap`?

Comment: I think it would be very useful to create a StackBlitz where you illustrate your problem and the expected results.